# Storing an array from array[x] to array[y] into another array

Tags: java

How can I store an array from x to y into another array?

For example I got this

```
int[] array = new int[x];
*reading*
int[]array1 = new int[4];
```

and I want to store from array[x] to array[y] into array1. How can I do this? I don't have the exact number. The length is determinated by the user's input.

Comment: Look into the `Arrays` class.

Comment: you probably mean to store the (first x) elements of the array?
iterate over array1, from 0 to (4-1). for each of them:
array1[nr] = array[nr];

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: I'm getting this on print [I@55f96302

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString` to get a decent String representation of the content of your array.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [Arrays.copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method.

```
int[] array = new int[]{1,2,...,n};
int[] array1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array,x,y+1); // y+1 because the second index is exclusive
```

a better definition of what `x` and `y` should be would help with the example, i.e. do you want the new array to be all elements from `array[x]` to the last element of `array`
if thats the case then `y` should be `array.length`.